# datatable - imported in order - Error : makeEditable is not a function -

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to edit dataTable,

JS code,

```
 function populateShowConfig(items)
 {
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#tbl-results').DataTable( {
      "bProcessing": true,
      responsive: true,
      "aaData": items,
      "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "name" },
            { "mDataProp": "value" }
    ]
    }).makeEditable({sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php"});
  });
}
```

i also included the library files in order as suggested in many stack overflow threads,

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.jeditable/1.7.3/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

but still getting the below error,

```
TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).makeEditable is not a function
```

I'm able to view the table but after that i get above erro  can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue got fixed, when i made the below change
Old code :

```
$('#tbl-results').DataTable({
```

New Code:

```
$('#tbl-results').dataTable( {
```